Microsoft access UNION is limiting the long text fields to 255 chars
im using a UNION statement to combine the records of two tables. The problem is that when im using this UNION the long fields that have length more than 255 chars are ommited in the 255th character.
When im using a single select then there is no problem at all. I found out that the problem is with the UNION statement. If i use union all the issue is fixed but i dont want to use UNION all.
Any ideas why is this happening? I have tried cast the fields but nothing is working

Right, 255 characters is the limitation.
Using a second query you may look up the full memo should you need it.
However, even if you directly can fill a memo field to 64K, a query will only retrieve 32K.
Even worse, if you fill a memo field with, say, the Rich Text Box control you can reach megabyte field content sizes while still only the first 32K are retrieved.
To circumvent this you may use DLookup to fetch the full content. Now, when the content is smaller than 32K it is waste of time to call DLookup; thus DLookup should only be used when necessary.
Here is an old method to achieve that:
Public Function LookupMemo( _
  ByVal strSource As String, _
  ByVal strFieldID As String, _
  ByVal strFieldMemo As String, _
  ByRef lngID As Long, _
  ByRef varMemo As Variant) _
  As String

' Extracts without truncation to 32768 characters the ' content of a memo field in a query.
'
' Assumes proper wrapping of table/field names containing spaces 
' like "[My field name]" and a single field unique numeric key.
'
' Typical usage (SQL):
'
'   SELECT
'     ID,
'     LookupMemo("Table1", "ID", "MemoField", [ID], [MemoField]) AS FullMemo
'   FROM
'     Table1;
'
' 2003-12-29. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  ' Maximum length of string from memo field when retrieved in a query.
  Const clngStrLen  As Long = &H8000&

  Dim strExpr       As String
  Dim strDomain     As String
  Dim strCriteria   As String
  Dim strMemo       As String
  Dim lngLen        As Long
  
  On Error GoTo Exit_LookupMemo

  If Not IsNull(varMemo) Then
    lngLen = Len(varMemo)
    If lngLen < clngStrLen Then
      ' The memo field is not truncated.
      strMemo = varMemo
    ElseIf Len(strSource) > 0 And Len(strFieldID) > 0 And Len(strFieldMemo) > 0 Then
      ' The memo is probably truncated by the query.
      ' Lookup the full memo in strSource.
      strExpr = strFieldMemo
      strDomain = strSource
      strCriteria = strFieldID & " = " & lngID & ""
      strMemo = vbNullString & DLookup(strExpr, strDomain, strCriteria)
    End If
  Else
    ' Return empty string.
  End If
  
  LookupMemo = strMemo

Exit_LookupMemo:
  Exit Function
  
Err_LookupMemo:
  ' Return empty string.
  Resume Exit_LookupMemo
  
End Function


wow thanks but is there a way to do it without this VBA code? Somehow cast in my select a max character len?

my fields will be max 1500 chars

You may try using UNION ALL. The use the query as source in yet a query where you use DISTINCT or GROUP BY to obtain the final result.

I have used UNION ALL and order by the four first columns
